# How to debug proguard rules?

Tags: android-studio, proguard

I am trying to debug my ProGuard rules after upgrading to Android Studio v2022.2.1 as the release build of my app has stopped working. I have checked the rules and found that adding `-dontshrink` to the `proguard-rules.pro` file resolved the issue.

However, the `usage.txt` file has a lot of content and I am not sure where to start debugging to identify the root cause of the problem. Can anyone provide me with some guidance on how to proceed with debugging my ProGuard rules?

PS: It's worth noting that the debug build does not have the same issue and the release build was working properly before the upgrade.